# Microsoft .NET Framework Unhandled exception

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 to copy the output (a lot of data) of the query to Excel spreadsheet. I keep getting the below Microsoft "Unhandled Exception" then SQL Server 2008 quits then I would have to restart everything all over again:

```
jitDebugging is already enabled in my machine (Windows 7)

Microsoft .NET Framework Unhanded exception

Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2009.0100.2500.00 ((KJ_PCU_Main).110617-0026 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5491 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

    <configuration>
        <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
    </configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: ...using SQL Server 2008 to copy the output...
are you using SSMS? can you be more specific of how exactly you're doing this?

Comment: I just copy the output of the query then paste it to excel spreadsheet. it works fine when dealing with less data but I would get the .Net Framework unhandled exception when working with large data

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain.

I have come across issues copying results from SSMS's Gridview --> Excel. The one I came across was related to a field containing a " (quote) -- it caused data to not show up in Excel! I filed it as a bug but never got a response:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/828677/ssms-copy-and-paste-into-excel-when-data-contains-a-double-quote-character

And that's not the only issue with pasting results into Excel from SSMS:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=excel%20paste

My suggestions are:

1. Output your results to a text file, then import into Excel.  Good because Excel doesn't like "a lot of data" anyway. Bad because it's just a plain-text file and your users want Excel.
2. If this is a single report you regularly need to run, you can save it as a comma/tab delimited file be changing your SELECT statement. When you open it from within Excel, your user will be guided to import it via a Wizard. It's kind of a hack:

`SELECT ISNULL(FIELD1) + CHAR(9) + ISNULL(FIELD2) + CHAR(9) + ISNULL(FIELD3)`

3. Use bcp.exe to export your data, but if you're going to hit the command line:
4. Create a PowerShell script. I build my query in SSMS then copy the query (not the results) to the clipboard and run my PS command. The PS script takes the clipboard and submits it to SQL via ADO.NET. PS will easily save the content to disk as a comma-delimited list or you can go hard-core Excel like this (added bonus if sending it via Email):

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Export-SQL-Data-67bcb690